# Description in google search + redirect metatag to fan page

Tags: redirect, seo, meta-tags

here is my problem...

there is this domain: dbrinterativa.com

when i try to seach for 'dbr' in google, it returns this website as the first option. but the problem is that the html has a metatag redirecting the user for a facebook fanpage... and google is getting this fanpage's descriptions and title!

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.facebook.com/dbrinterativa">
```

and there is another problem...

when i try to search for its url in google like dbrinterativa.com ([url of example](https://www.google.com.br/#hl=pt-BR&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=dbrinterativa.com&oq=dbrinterativa.com&gs_l=hp.3...2871.2871.0.3443.1.1.0.0.0.0.207.207.2-1.1.0...0.0...1c.2.VBZu2-EqSVQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=d1416af466825db0&bpcl=38093640&biw=1223&bih=829)) it says that the robots.txt is not allowing google to get its meta datas... here is a link to my [robots.txt](http://dbrinterativa.com/robots.txt)

does anybody knows what can i do to solve this problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking your robots, anyway not disallow facebook because you are using a meta refresh which is not a good practice.
So the crawler join in your website and after go to facebook, no matter what you have in your robots because not is following your robots anymore.

So I dont know why u are redirecting directly to facebook. You could do a website with a link to your FB page then you will be indexed correctly.

From the crawler of Google think that your website is the FB page, so for that is taking the title and description from your FB page and not from yours.

Comment: thx Javier... the problem is that i must redirect the user right in the time he gets in the website (that's cause we are still creating our site). do you know a way i can redirect him to my fan page, and still get my title and description in google?

Comment: If you want do directly redirect it´s black hat so google will not index to you well anyway. Maybe if you will do the redirect with javascript will take your title and description. Anyway, as I said you would have bad position on Google.